# How to display Xml file in JSP?

Tags: xml, jsp

I need to display a XML file in JSP page (raw XML file). pleas advise me with the necessary steps.

Comment: What does that mean? Do you need the JSP to return XML content, or read a local XML file and return that as the result? What does having the JSP "adds" to just serving the XML directly?

Comment: Yes, I want to display the local XML documents content as is in my JSP page.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
<%@page import="java.io.*"><%
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("abc.xml"));
try {
    OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
    int i;
    while ((i = is.read(b)) > -1) {
        os.write(b, 0, i);
    }
} finally {
    is.close();
}
    %>
```

Note that for what you are doing, a servlet is probably much better suited. Using JSP might introduce whitespaces, etc., and corrupt your document.